# How to add images to StandardTile in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

I am new to the SAPUI5 framework.

I have been facing issue while adding images to a `StandardTile` in SAPUI5. So kindly answer me whether it's possible to add images to a `StandardTile` or not.

I have tried all the possible ways to add the images to the `StandardTile` but I am not getting a solution.

I can add images to a `CustomTile` but not to a `StandardTile`.

Please check my following code:

```js
new sap.m.StandardTile({
    content: [
        new sap.m.Image({
            width: "220px",
            height: "250px",
            src: "splitapp/images/Shirt-1.jpg"
        })
    ]
})

new sap.m.CustomTile({
    content: [
        new sap.m.Image({
            width: "220px",
            height: "300px",
            src: "splitapp/images/Shirt-2.jpg"
        })
    ]
})
```

Comment: As you can see from the API, `sap.m.StandardTile` does not have a `content` aggregation, whereas `sap.m.CustomTile` does. You can, however, specify an image for the `icon` property

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [API documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.StandardTile.html) or the [Explored App](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.StandardTile/properties) for the StandardTile.

The StandardTile does not support any generic `content`, but allows you to add an image (or icon) using the `icon` property:

```js
new sap.m.StandardTile({
    icon: "splitapp/images/Shirt-1.jpg"
});
```